# Does the Golden Switch also prevent Wrath cookies?

Tags: cookie-clicker

The Golden Switch Prestige Upgrade prevents "Golden Cookies" from spawning in exchange for a +50% CpS bonus. Other parts of the game specifically call out "Wrath Cookies" and "Golden Cookies" separately while things like the Stat "Golden Cookies Clicked" combines them. Does the switch only affect Golden Cookies or does it treat all cookies the same?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The switch treats both the same.
You won't get any golden or wrath cookies and receive a 50% (or higher, if you also have the prestige upgrade for 100000 chips) bonus to your cookie production.